# PHP RegEx + Delete dot after a word

Tags: php, regex

Inside a string I have several words with a dot; e.g.:

> lorem 1.5 ipsum. Cratea lopusus.

After many tests, I don't see how to delete the dots, if the dot is after a word. For example, I want to get this string:

> lorem 1.5 ipsum Cratea lopusus

I have tested with this many regular expressions without success:

```
/\.\b/     /[.]\b/    /[\.]\b/ ...
```

Can you give me an example to remove the dots (placed dots after a word)?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should have tried with `\.\B` where `\B` is a non-word boundary. All the three patterns you used are equal. If you want to make sure the dot comes after a word char, use `\b\.\B`.

Comment: You can see if preceding character is a letter using `(?<=[a-z])\.` or `([a-z])\.`

Comment: @wiktor, it's ok with your pattern: \b\.\B . The dot is deleted after each word. Thanks ;) Here is my code : preg_replace("/\b\.\B/", "", $value);

Answer (score -1):

You can use preg_replace() function like that

```
$str = 'lorem 1.5 ipsum. Cratea lopusus.';
$result = preg_replace('/([^0-9])\./', '${1}', $str);
```

Comment: with your solution, the last character (of each word with a dot) seems to be deleted.

Comment: This actually works for the given example, but may be buggy in other situations. Example, try testing against a string like .. "lorem 1.5 ipsum. Cratea lopusus34. I want $. gimme now. abc.def and stuff. well . not this"

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```
\b\.\B
```

This will match all periods that come after a word boundary and before a non-word boundary. However, some things to consider:

- The definition of "word chars" per your regex flavor
- If you will have a non-word char preceding the period that you need to match. E.g., it will not match the period in - "I want $. gimme now"

Otherwise, you can use specific character set `[]` instead of `\b`

```
/([a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()]+)\.\B/  

preg_replace("/([a-zA-Z!@#$%^&*()]+)\.\B/", "\${1}", $str);
```

Note the character set I'm using is just an example, you could modify as needed.